# How to repeat execution until user input is correct in Java?

Tags: java

im beginner in java programing, have task need to be completed and looking for some useful tips. writing program which requires from user correct Float input, if input is incorrect, program gives another chance until correct input, my problem is next, when i enter incorrect input it runs non stop,, any ideas?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    float f = 0;
    int x = 1;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter an float:");
            f = in.nextFloat();
            x =2;

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("Incorrect entry.");

        }
        System.out.println("Your entry is:" + f);

    }
    while(x==1);
}
```

Comment: Add `in.nextLine();` at the end of your `while` loop, to swallow the rest of the line.

Comment: What we can consider a correct input in this case well i have executed the program for input 3,7,45.45 it only runs once.Any example of  incorrect input ??

Comment: incorect input can be anything, letters for example, input jbvirebv and you will see, correct input, is floating number,

Comment: ill try that now Berger

Comment: in.nextLine(); doesnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and you will get the output you want from your program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        float f = 0;
        int x = 1;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter an float:");
                f = in.nextFloat();
                x = 2;

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect entry.");
                in.next();

            }

        } while (x == 1);
        System.out.println("Your entry is:" + f);

    }
```

You just need to add `in.next()` in catch block to continue the process.

Comment: thanks a lot @abhishekkumar, now it works

Comment: please choose this as accepted answer if your problem is resolved

Comment: i did mate. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, you may want to :

1) Check that the next token is a float `hasNextFloat()`

2) If it isn't, swallow the whole line `nextLine()`

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        float f = 0;
        String entry;
        int x = 1;
        do {

            System.out.print("Enter an float:");

            if (in.hasNextFloat()) {

                f = in.nextFloat();
                entry = Float.toString(f);
                x = 2;

            } else {

                entry = in.nextLine();
                System.err.println("Incorrect entry.");

            }
            System.out.println("Your entry is: " + entry);

        } while (x == 1);
```

This has the advantage of getting rid, of wrong input line having multiple tokens (e.g : "aa bb cc").